# Need to find the difference of one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find the difference where I have the column with n. number of students where the students are differentiated with Phase 1, Phase 2, Final.

For example one column is of students and another is with Phase Type.

```
   **Students**          **Phase Type**
   BALIPOGU SUNITHA        Phase 1
   GUDIPATI RAJESH         Phase 1
   GUDIPATI RAJESH         Phase 2
   KATUBOYINA YESWANTH     Phase 1
   VADITHYA RAHUL NAIK     Phase 1
   VADITHYA RAHUL NAIK     Phase 2
   VADITHYA RAHUL NAIK     Final
   BANDARU NANDIVARDHAN    Phase 1
   DODAGATTE SAI PREETHI   Phase 1
   G SHIRISHA G SHIRISHA   Phase 1
   KODASU OMKAR            Phase 1
   DUDEKULA KHAJA VALI     Phase 1 
   DUDEKULA KHAJA VALI     Phase 2
   DUDEKULA KHAJA VALI     Final
   RANGA SUDHA RANI        Phase 1
   RANGA SUDHA RANI        Phase 2
```

From the above list I need to retrieve the data of the students of phase 1 and phase 2, phase 2 and Final.

And the count of the difference.

List of Students of Phase 2 which are not present in Phase 1 and list of the student of Final which are not present in Phase 2 and the total count.

Expected OutPut:

```
   **diff of Phase 1 & Phase 2**         **Diff of Phase 2 & Final**
   BALIPOGU SUNITHA                          GUDIPATI RAJESH      
   KATUBOYINA YESWANTH                       RANGA SUDHA RANI
   BANDARU NANDIVARDHAN    
   DODAGATTE SAI PREETHI  
   G SHIRISHA G SHIRISHA   
   KODASU OMKAR
```

Comment: You can add your expected output here for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into TEST values('raju','Phase 1')
insert into TEST values('ramu','Phase 2')
insert into TEST values('rajesh','Phase 1')
insert into TEST values('raghu','Phase 2')
insert into TEST values('rahul','Final')
insert into TEST values('sunny','Final')
insert into TEST values('kanna','Phase 1')
insert into TEST values('neeraj','Phase 2')
insert into TEST values('rajesh','Phase 2')
insert into TEST values('raghu','Phase 1')

--Nr of students per phase
SELECT PHASE_TYPE, COUNT(STUDENTS)
FROM TEST
GROUP BY PHASE_TYPE
ORDER BY PHASE_TYPE;

--Students in both Phase 1 and Phase 2
select t1.STUDENTS, concat(t1.phase_type,' and ', t2.phase_type) as PHASE 
from 
(SELECT STUDENTS, PHASE_TYPE
 FROM TEST
 WHERE
 PHASE_TYPE = 'Phase 1'
) t1
inner join 
(SELECT STUDENTS, PHASE_TYPE
FROM TEST 
WHERE
 PHASE_TYPE = 'Phase 2'
) t2
on t1.STUDENTS = t2.STUDENTS
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer

Comment: Thanks for your interest,As you suggested with your answer i had been tried with it already but what i have expected was not the correct output.

Comment: Now once again i had been rewritten my question with the expected output,please can you help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, classify each student.  You can do this using aggregation:

```
select student,
       (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Phase 1') > 0) as has_phase1,
       (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Phase 2') > 0) as has_phase2,
       (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Final') > 0) as has_final
from test
group by student;
```

Then the simplest method is `union all`:

```
with cte as (
      select student,
             (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Phase 1') > 0) as has_phase1,
             (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Phase 2') > 0) as has_phase2,
             (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Final') > 0) as has_final
      from test
      group by student
     )
select 'Phase 1 & Phase 2', student
from cte
where has_phase1 and has_phase2
union all
select 'Phase 2 & Final', student
from cte
where has_phase2 and has_final;
```

You can put this into two columns, if you really want:

```
with cte as (
      select student,
             (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Phase 1') > 0) as has_phase1,
             (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Phase 2') > 0) as has_phase2,
             (count(*) filter (where phase = 'Final') > 0) as has_final
      from test
      group by student
     )
select p12.student as phase_1_2,
       p2f.student as phase_2_f
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (order by student) as seqnum
      from cte
      where has_phase1 and has_phase2
     ) p12 full join
     (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (order by student) as seqnum
      from cte
      where has_phase2 and has_final
     ) p2f
     using (seqnum)
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: Is there any other option instead of filter,because the filter function is not been supported in Postgresql 9.1  verion.

Comment: @sumithsunny . . . You can use `sum( phase = 'Phase 1')::int )` instead.